# Draw points, lines and labels on satellite images

Tags: python, labeling, point, line

I need to draw points, lines and labels on satellite images. The image has the size A0, a small example is below. The number of drawn objects is equal to several thousands. So give me advice which Python library can be used for solving the problem effectively. Also, I need to control the position of the labels because their overlapping is not allowed.

[image]

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: I am developing own project. Satellite images, points, lines are input data.

Comment: Is the photo geo-referenced? Do the lines, points, labels have geo-coordinates?

Comment: Yes. The photo is geo-referenced. I need to draw some additional objects using Python